# Fruits are running away ! Stored Procedure SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a table like this,

Table - Fruits

```
ID
Fruit_Truck_ID
Fruit_Crate_ID (can be null)
Mango (column exists but might get deleted)  (these columnns are bit)
Apple
etc etc...
```

Now, what I want is that, create a stored procedure, which will either provide (truck id + fruit name) or provide (truck id + crate id + fruit name)

Fruit Columns can be added and deleted so I need to make a stored procedure which do following,

- If in table, if fruit crate id is not null then select using truck id and crate id + given name of column, e.g. if I give this,    GetFruitMango(truck_ID, Crate_ID, "Mango", it should return me the value of mango column which is bit (0 or 1)

Now if Crate_ID provided is not in table or is null then use truck_ID and Column name to get what's in mango column etc.

Comment: UNPIVOT and dynamic query.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan can I use it in DataAccess based on typed dataset, thanks

Comment: Do you want to do it on client side?

Comment: Nope, within stored procedure, which will be called within a dataaccess project, later on assembl of dataaccess will be used in other applications

Comment: Have you problem with SP or SP call? I think first.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan am lost now.

Comment: This is what you want? But what have you tried so far? Do you have problem with SP? Again, those fields `mango,apple,banana` are those dynamic OR they exist in table?

Comment: @Rahul I created table, other stored procedure, for this one I don't where to start and these are columns not fields... , please read question, it clearly says that columns are there but might get deleted, so I want to just want to provide name of columns....

Comment: Instead of `BIT` columns for `Mango, Apple, etc`, I would unpivot the table structure.  Add a `FruitName` column and a `BIT` column (something like `FruitExists`).

Comment: That's a horrible database design. Adding or removing a column whenever a new fruit comes into play or is no longer needed? You should rather change that instead of trying to circumvent issues with a tricky stored procedure. Even the table name Fruits doesn't match its content. If you have the opportunity to change the data model do it now.

Comment: I believe columns and fields are synonym. Moreover, that's a poor DB design. try normalizing your table else in longer run you are bound to get into trouble. example. your procedure name `GetFruitMango` when you are trying to search for mango. What if you are searching for apple you will create another SP with different name? Rather, create a varchar column for fruit. I don't see any reason for a bit columns for every fruit.